# MongoDB aggregate nested values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In a MongoDB collection, there is data nested in an `absence` array.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c6c62f3d0e85e6ae3a8c842"),
"absence" : [
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2017-05-10T17:00:00.000-07:00"),
        "code" : "E",
        "type" : "E",
        "isPartial" : false
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-02-24T16:00:00.000-08:00"),
        "code" : "W",
        "type" : "E",
        "isPartial" : false
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-02-23T16:00:00.000-08:00"),
        "code" : "E",
        "type" : "E",
        "isPartial" : false
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-02-21T16:00:00.000-08:00"),
        "code" : "U",
        "type" : "U",
        "isPartial" : false
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-02-20T16:00:00.000-08:00"),
        "code" : "R",
        "type" : "E",
        "isPartial" : false
    }
]
}
```

I'd like to aggregate by `absence.type` to return a count of every type and the total number of `absence` children. The results might look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6c62f3d0e85e6ae3a8c842"),
    "U" : 1,
    "E" : 4,
    "total" : 5
}
```

There are several similar questions posted here but I'm yet to successfully adapt the answers my schema. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, are there GUI modeling tools to help with MongoDB query building? The transition from RDBMS queries to the Mongo aggregation pipeline has been quite difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {  
        $unwind: "$absence" 
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { _id: "$_id", type: "$absence.type" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id._id",
            types: { $push: { k: "$_id.type", v: "$count" } },
            total: { $sum: "$count" }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [ "$$ROOT", { $arrayToObject: "$types" } ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            types: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) allows you to get single document per `absence`. Then you need double [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html), first one to count by `type` and `_id` and second one to aggregate the data per `_id`. Having one document per `_id` you just need [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) with [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) to promote your dynamically created keys and values (by [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html)) to the root level.

output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c6c62f3d0e85e6ae3a8c842"), "total" : 5, "U" : 1, "E" : 4 }
```

Comment: That nearly did it, @mickl. Thank you. The root level object contains other fields I want to return in my projection. What do I need to do to project out those additional fields?

Imagine there is a `firstname`field in the data at the same level as the absences array. Thanks!

Comment: You can add `firstname: { $first: 'firstname' }` in both `$group` stages

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the possible values of "absence.type" then $filter the array on the value and compute the $size of the filtered array.  This won't work if you don't know all the possible values in the "absence.type".

```
db.col.aggregate([

    { $project: { U: { $size: { $filter: { input: "$absence", as: "a", cond: { $eq: [ "$$a.type", "U"]}  }}}, 
                    E: { $size: { $filter: { input: "$absence", as: "a", cond: { $eq: [ "$$a.type", "E"]}  }}} }},
    { $project: { total: { $add: [ "$U", "$E" ]}, U: 1, E: 1}},

])
```